# SQL counting values and selecting Column Name as result

Tags: sql

I am new to SQL and a little embarrassed to ask this.

I have A table that contains 2 columns A and B

```
A  B
0  2
1  3
3  1
```

I want a query that will return

```
Category | Sum

A           4
B           6
```

What is the best way to write this query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select 'A', sum(A) from table
union
select 'B', sum(B) from table
```

Answer (score 0):

Or this...

```
 SELECT  SUM(A) A
 , SUM(B) B
 FROM @MyTable
```

Answer (score 0):

If UNPIVOT is supported by the SQL product you are using:

```
SELECT Category, SUM(Value) AS Sum
FROM atable
UNPIVOT (Value FOR Category IN (A, B)) u
GROUP BY Category
;
```

In particular, the above syntax works in [Oracle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f4b4f2/1) and [SQL Server](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f4b4f/1).